# Forms Authentication issue with URL Re-write

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis-8

Updated based on my current findings:

I'm using Forms Authentication on a website that runs asp.net 4.5 applications in IIS 8.5.

In addition, I'm using URLRewrite that re-directs two applications to a different server after the Forms Authentication has taken place.

One of the application is a .aspx form based web application which works fine. The other is an MVC 5 application --- this one does not work. I keep getting a 401 error in the IIS log, and the following text in the Application event log:

Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied was invalid.

Each application has its own unique app pool, both are version 4.0, but one app pool is classic, and one is integrated. The one that's integrated is the one that's failing.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It's unlikely this would have anything to do with bitness.  The .net framework installs both 32 and 64 bit versions of the framework (including the forms authentication module).  I think you're on a wild goose chase

Comment: ASP.NET web app bitness is controlled by the application pool bitness, not what you specify in project files. Edit your question to include the actual error in event log, and then there might be some discussion around it.

Comment: Make sure to clear your browser cache between attempts against that site.  Also look for MachineKey configuration in the Application's Web.config to make sure its not using its own custom config.

Comment: Believe I solved this: the problem was in the web.config files. I changed the targetFramework element value in both the Compilation tag and the httpRuntime tag in the failing application to match of that application that set the FormsAuthentication cookie. Probably could have modified the machineKey values in the different .NET runtime configuration files to make sure they were all consistent as well, but this seemed to be a simpler (if not more correct) fix. I truly hope this helps somebody because it was hard for me to figure out!